# CategoryPanelGroup No Header

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Can anyone tell me how to prevent the TCategoryPanelGroup from drawing the headers.  I've attempted to set the header.height to 0 but that creates and entirely new problem.  My panels have TImages on them and when I scroll the panel group, graphic artifacts get drawn on the TImage.

Unfortunately, I don't appear to be able to post an image to show you so here's how to reproduce what I see.

- New form. Drop a TCategoryPanelGroup on it, align client.
- Add a new panel and drop a TImage on the panel, align left (you don't even have to load an image)
- Copy and paste this panel several times into the PanelGroup
- Set the TCategoryPanelGroup.HeaderHeight to 0.
- Run the app.

Resize it so that you have a vertical scroll bar.
Scroll the panels and if you're like me, you'll see some graphic artifacts where the TImage is.

[image: TCategoryPanelGroup Img Artifacts]

Here's a rough of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're usingi wrong component for the job - why do you use `TCategoryPanelGroup` and not for examle scrollbox?

Comment: The image would help. Put it in a paste box, and leave a link in a question edit. Then we'll convert it into inline image. And I've given you a couple of upvotes to kick start your rep so that you can post images in future.

Comment: I'm trying to duplicate the look of a DBCtrlGrid but I don't need data aware. I also need to be able to drag and drop to rearrange the panels (which I can mostly do) and drag them to another PanelGroup.  So far, the PanelGroup is the closest control I've found to doing this. I don't want the headers tho, they're ugly.

Comment: I thot about doing it in a scrollbox but decided it would be too difficult... like this is sooo easy.  I may just take ain's advice, scrap all this and do it in a scrollbox.

Comment: You said you were using XE. You appear to be using VCL styles. And XE does not have VCL styles. That would have been very pertinent information at your last question too.

Comment: Sorry David, using XE3. And yes, I did mention in my last question I was using XE3. I didn't see a tag for XE3. Rather new to the forums here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the artefact you can override DrawHeader of TCategoryPanel

```
type
  TCategoryPanel=Class(ExtCtrls.TCategoryPanel)
    procedure DrawHeader;override;
  End;

  TForm3 = class(TForm)
//.........
procedure TCategoryPanel.DrawHeader;
begin
//  inherited;

end;
```